# Why is if x in (1,2,3): faster than if x ==1 or x ==2 or x ==3:

Tags: python, performance, pylint

According to http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2.0.html the in option is faster than the multiple ors.

To quote from the site

> A new check was added, consider-using-in.
>
> This refactoring message is emitted when a variable is compared
> against multiple values concatenated by ors instead of using the
> faster, more idiomatic "in" check.
>
> if variable == 1 or variable == 2 or variable == 3:  # bad
> pass
>
> if variable in (1, 2, 3):  # good
> pass

Firstly, is the in option faster? Because surely it has to do the same as the multiple ors and wouldn't the memory penalty of creating the tuple each time not be worth it?

Comment: With `in` you're performing *one* operation which is implemented and optimised in C. With multiple `or`s, you're performing three separate operations.

Comment: Compare `dis.dis(lambda x: x == 1 or x == 2 or x == 3)` to `dis.dis(lambda x: x in (1, 2, 3))` - fewer loads, fewer comparisons.

Comment: Because `in` is a keyword, which is well optimized. You should use library functions whenever you should to make your code fast

Comment: if `x` is always `1` then the `or` version will be faster

Comment: Performance should practically never be a consideration here to begin with

Comment: and does anyone have a preference for whether it should be a tuple, list or set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On one hand, there's a [constant-folding optimization](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.3/Python/ast_opt.c#L272) that'll precompute constant tuples, so `in (1, 2, 3)` doesn't go through the expense of building the whole tuple each time. Without needing to build the tuple every time, the `in` approach actually has less bytecode interpretation overhead and runs quicker than the `==` approach.

On the other hand, this only applies to constant tuples. `in` is often slower when the tuple is not a compile-time constant, such as `in (x, y, z)`. Pylint will report `consider-using-in` even in cases where `in` would be slower.

I think Pylint will even report `consider-using-in` in cases where `in` would change the meaning of the code, like `x == 1 or x == thing_with_side_effects()`.

Comment: You're right that constant folding won't apply if you call a function, but it will apply even if it's not for tuples: it also works for lists and, [as of Python 3.2](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations), to set literals. Indeed it would make a bit more sense to use a set literal if you're about to test with `in`.

Comment: @ArthurTacca it would make the most sense to not consider minute perforamance differences in the first place, and to consider maintainability and code clarity first. And the performance isn't that straight-forward anyway, the tuple will take (slightly) longer in the worst case, but is (slightly) faster in the best case (first item). We're talking on the order of 10 nanoseconds to begin with.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I actually agree with that, the focus of the my comment was more the first half, which corrected the statement "this only applies to tuples". But using a set actually reflects your *intent* better than a tuple (a tuple suggests you care about the order of comparisons, which is confusing for something like `(1, 2, 3)` where comparison order doesn't matter) so probably better to use a set even from just a pure code clarity point of view.

Comment: @ArthurTacca I believe what user2357112 was trying to say there is not that it only applies to *tuples* but that it only applies when the literal expression only involves constants.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes I thought so to but was worried that, because that's not what it literally says, someone else could've misread it.

Answer (score 1):

As is often the case, I think pylint is wrong. It isn't always the case that this is true. It is *only* true of the tuple can be cached as a constant in the bytecod compilation step, which isn't always the case. Consider the simple:

```
In [1]: def using_in(a, b, c):
   ...:     42 in (a,b,c)
   ...:

In [2]: def using_or(a, b, c):
   ...:     42 == a or 42 == b or 42 == c
   ...:

In [3]: %timeit using_in(1,2,3)
125 ns ± 3.82 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit using_or(1,2,3)
119 ns ± 1.96 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

But more importantly, these sorts of decisions should almost always be about code clarity or maintainability. Performance difference are often negligible anyway.

Honestly, if you are writing your code to optimize at this level, CPython probably isn't the runtime for you.

Comment: +1 for your main point about code clarity. Just to add a contrasting point about speed: if the left hand side is something complex then the `in` version would be faster (`foo() in (a, b, c)` vs `foo() == a or foo() == b or foo() == c`). In fairness, as well as PyLint calling the tuple version "faster" (which as you say could be wrong), it also calls it "more idiomatic". I certainly find the `in` version easier to read, and maybe that PyLint's main point.

Comment: @ArthurTacca well, that would just be lazy coding. You should do `value = foo(); value == a or value == b or value == c` but definitely, I see that out in the wild (it drives me nuts). It is actually one of the reasons for assignment expressions!

Comment: The performance difference is not visible mainly because of the cost of the function call which take about 70% of the time on my machine. Moreover, the constant-folding optimization is not possible anymore in the first case because of the non-constant function parameters (which make the `in`-based version much slower). Thus, I think this test does not exactly measure what the OP intended to do.

Comment: @JérômeRichard yes, my point was pylint is suggesting something that isn't always the case. And yes, the majority of the time is spent on the function-call overhead. That doesn't really detract from my point that the *absolute* difference is marginal, even removing the function call, I'm getting something like 4-5 nanoseconds difference. This is tiny. You'd have to be repeating something hundreds of millions of times for it to have a sizable effect. If you are optimizing at that level, CPython is not the runtime for you (think of the gargantuan function call overhead).